# Converting LabColor to sRGBColor in colormath gives invalid hex

Tags: python, python-2.7, xmp, lab-color-space, colormath

I have the following methods:

```
def labProcessColorSwatch(node, namespaces):
    return {
        "name": node.find(".//xmpG:swatchName", namespaces).text,
        "color_type": node.find(".//xmpG:type", namespaces).text,
        "tint": node.find(".//xmpG:tint", namespaces).text,
        "source_type": node.find(".//xmpG:mode", namespaces).text,
        "display": '',
        "source": {
            "L*": node.find(".//xmpG:L", namespaces).text,
            "a*": node.find(".//xmpG:A", namespaces).text,
            "b*": node.find(".//xmpG:B", namespaces).text,
        }
    }

def labToHex(swatch):
    lab = LabColor(
        lab_l = float(swatch["source"]["L*"]),
        lab_a = float(swatch["source"]["a*"]),
        lab_b = float(swatch["source"]["b*"])
    )
    rgb = convert_color(lab, sRGBColor)
    return bitConvertHex(rgb) # rgb.get_rgb_hex()
```

Using Xmp datasource:

```
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
   <xmpG:swatchName>PANTONE 1505 C</xmpG:swatchName>
   <xmpG:type>SPOT</xmpG:type>
   <xmpG:tint>100.000000</xmpG:tint>
   <xmpG:mode>LAB</xmpG:mode>
   <xmpG:L>66.274513</xmpG:L>
   <xmpG:A>59</xmpG:A>
   <xmpG:B>93</xmpG:B>
</rdf:li>
```

Gives:

```
sRGBColor(rgb_r=1.0543146152492686,rgb_g=0.42327948385100367,rgb_b=0.0)
set([0, 108, 269])
{'color_type': 'SPOT',
 'display': '#10d6c00',
 'name': 'PANTONE 1505 C',
 'source': {'L*': '66.274513', 'a*': '59', 'b*': '93'},
 'source_type': 'LAB',
 'tint': '100.000000'}
```

Why is this calculating a `#10d6c00` hexcode value? 269 is obviously wrong, but Lab, I'm not following how this may be wrong (except something about scaling the `L` or `R` value 0-255 > 0-100?).

This is using colormath 2.1.1.

Comment: don't declare function with camalCase, i saw that you write in javascript, in javascript you can you camalCase but here in python use please use > `Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.`

Comment: So a downvote for camelcase? What?

Comment: Fair enough. There's nothing wrong with this question. I also have an answer. I don't program in Python ever, so I'm not concerned about their conventions at the moment. Thanks though, I didn't know that. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough, the color is outside the representable range for sRGB. Switching to the clamped methods resolves the issue:

```
def bitConvertHex(color):
    # Scale up to 0-255 values.
    rgb_r = int(math.floor(0.5 + color.clamped_rgb_r * 255))
    rgb_g = int(math.floor(0.5 + color.clamped_rgb_g * 255))
    rgb_b = int(math.floor(0.5 + color.clamped_rgb_b * 255))
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (rgb_r, rgb_g, rgb_b)
```

Thanks to Magnus The Nordlander for the tip.